# Change a custom UINavigationController property in all instances

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to make an option where the user can define navigationBar background color. (I made a simple version to ask here)

I'm using a custom UINavigationController called CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController with this implementation:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = .orange
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

And this custom UINavigationController is embed in several ViewControllers.

[image: UIViewControllers with UINavigationControllers embed]

So by default the navigationBar for Custom NavigationController is orange.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func redButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let navController = navigationController as! CustomNavigationController
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
}

@IBAction func orangeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let navController = navigationController as! CustomNavigationController
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .orange
}
}
```

The Second View Controller can edit the color of his embed navigationController.

My question is: How can i change the color of all CustomNavigationControllers instances to keep color changed for all across the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can access all instances of CustomNavigationController like this:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.forEach { controller in
    if let controller = controller as? CustomNavigationController {
        controller.customBarTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Also change your CustomNavigationController implementation to something like below, otherwise the color will be reset to orange on every layout call.

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var customBarTintColor: UIColor = .orange {
        didSet {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = customBarTintColor
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.barTintColor = customBarTintColor
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

In order to change color of navigation bar for all view controllers

You can set all `UINavigationBar` in your application use
`UINavigationBar.appearance()` to set all property. [more](https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift)